# When using the Lucky feat to reroll an attack against me, do I add any modifiers to the reroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Part of the [Lucky](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/lucky) feat (PHB, p. 167) says:

> You can also spend one luck point when an attack roll is made against you. Roll a d20, and then choose whether the attack uses the attacker's roll or yours.

**When using the Lucky feat to reroll an attack against me, do I add any modifiers to the reroll?**

Say the attacker's roll for example is a 23 (1d20 + 6 (prof. bonus + relevant ability score modifier), with a roll of 17 on the die); I use Lucky to force a reroll, and there's a 15 rolled on the die. Do I add the attacker's proficiency to the 1d20 that I rolled for the replacement? Or do I keep it as it is, as 15?

Comment: Related: [Can luck points be used after attack rolls against me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55355/can-luck-points-be-used-after-attack-rolls-against-me), [Does the Lucky feat allow the character to see the enemy's die roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116018/does-the-lucky-feat-allow-the-character-to-see-the-enemys-die-roll)

Answer (score 10):

## The modifier is added to whichever die roll you choose

The roll is the result of the dice; the +6 is the modifier. That is added to either roll result.

This means you may choose from either 23 (die roll of 17 + the modifier of 6) or 21 (the roll of 15 + 6).

Comment: I was going to suggest touching on who actually adds the modifier and whether the player knows the enemy's exact roll, but those are apparently already covered by the related questions I linked in my comment above.