# What happens if you get over 20 on a death save?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, saving-throw

Normally with when you roll death saves, you get up with 1 HP if you roll a 20. But how does this apply with modifiers like Bless?

> You bless up to three creatures of your choice within range. Whenever
> a target makes an attack roll or a saving throw before the spell ends,
> the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to the attack roll
> or saving throw.

Would Bless bringing it to 20 or over count for the waking back up function?

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Can Bless or Bardic Inspiration help a creature from rolling a 1 on a death save?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156433)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## You get a success and nothing more

Only rolling a natural 20 or a natural 1 has any predetermined effect when making a [death save throw](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageandHealing). When one of those is rolled, you follow the rule below:

> When you make a death saving throw and roll a 1 on the d20, it counts as two failures. If you roll a 20 on the d20, you regain 1 hit point.

Comment: the reason i posted a very similar answer is because I think the title of your answer contradicts the content.
If one rolls a 20 on the die, wich makes 21 with a +1 bonus, according to the title it counts as a normal success and according to the content it makes you regain 1hp

Comment: @AnneAunyme I'm not sure I agree with that (and i'm not sure the other who have upvoted do either.) But the end result is a get a success, nothing more. THe reason why is in the body that only a natural 20 or 1 matters. Can I be clearer? Your answer covers the other side of the coin in that you don't use modifiers. It's another way of saying only natural roll matters.

Comment: Even though the PHB says "a success or failure has no effect by itself", saying only a natural 1/20 has any effect is still a little confusing since other values still count as success/failure. Maybe "counts when calculating a success or failure, but doesn't have any other effect" or something along those lines.

Comment: In fact, if you somehow acquired a +20 to your roll, it would be "2 failures and nothing more" if you rolled a natural 1 =)

Answer (score 16):

### What counts is the number on the die, not the final result.

From the rules:

> Rolling 1 or 20. When you make a death saving throw and roll a 1 on
> the d20, it counts as two failures. If you roll a 20 on the d20, you
> regain 1 hit point.

You specifically need the number that appear on the D20 to be either 1 or 20 for those effects to trigger, not to have the total roll with modifiers equal to 1 or 20.

Bless is taken into account to determine if the saving throw is a success or a failure, but not in the specific case of the "1 or 20" rule.

Comment: The final result definitely matters - it’s a matter of life and death.

Comment: This would be more clear if it explicitly stated that bless does not affect death saving throws. Only the number on the die matters. There are no modifiers.

Comment: @BobTheAverage  "You are in the hands of fate now, aided only by spells and features that improve your chances of succeeding on a saving throw."  Bless does not say it does not affect death saves.  Death saves says it is affected by spells.  Why do you say there are no modifiers?

Comment: Bless is taken into account to determine if the saving throw is a success or a failure, but not in the specific case of the "1 or 20" rule.